# How to fix Large Ugly Switch buttons in Gtk.ListBox for GTK/LibHandy snippet

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

Created a simple list box using python, gtk and libhandy. Unfortunately, I can't figure out why the switch boxes are so big (and ugly). They don't look natural at all.

```
gi.require_version('Handy', '0.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Handy


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

            # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Window.html
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.set_title("Switches Example")
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_size_request(350, 350)

            # Create List Box
            # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ListBox.html 
        box = Gtk.ListBox()
        box.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)

            # use the libhandy function to add separators to listbox rows
            # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Handy-0.0/functions.html#Handy.list_box_separator_header
        box.set_header_func(Handy.list_box_separator_header)

            # Add some rows
        box.add(self.addrow("London"))
        box.add(self.addrow("Berlin"))
        box.add(self.addrow("Prague"))

            # Add List box to main window
        self.add(box)


    def addrow(self, title):

            # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Handy-0.0/classes/ActionRow.html
        row = Handy.ActionRow()
        row.set_title(title)

            # Add action to row
        row.add_action(Gtk.Switch.new())
        return row

    # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Handy-0.0/functions.html#Handy.init 
Handy.init()

window = MyWindow()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Currently, switch buttons look like this (large and ugly).
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3W3U.png)

This is the expected look
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J12hI.png)

How do I make the switch buttons look like the expected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is subjective and a bit unclear. What does "natural" mean? Could you clarify what you're asking some more? For example: "How do I make the button smaller". It would also be helpful to have more information about what you've tried to do to change the button's appearance. For example: "I tried using X method from the Gtk documentation, but it only did Y when I was expecting Z." Lastly, since this is a graphical rendering question, consider uploading an image of your current result and a mockup of your desired result.

Comment: Originally, I couldn't post the images b/c of my lack of reputation points. I've added images current vs expected. It should be obvious to see that one looks enlarged and streched and the other is fitting of the size.

Comment: Okay, the images are helpful, though I'd still recommend focusing your question by turning it into specific, technical needs (ex. "How can I resize a GTK ListBox?"). Also, can you provide some details on what you've done to troubleshoot the problem so far? For example, have you looked in the [GTK documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes) and tried changing any style properties?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `valign` property of the `Gtk.Switch` to `Gtk.Align.CENTER`, the default is `Gtk.Align.FILL`

```py
def addrow(self, title):
    # https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Handy-0.0/classes/ActionRow.html
    row = Handy.ActionRow()
    row.set_title(title)

    # Add action to row
    switch = Gtk.Switch()
    switch.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
    row.add_action(switch)

    return row
```